# Very Basic terminal in Java

Tags: java, swing, ssh, terminal

I need to execute 5 - 10 commands from a Java application (that runs on windows and linux) to an SSH server and show the output of these commands in a JFrame. The output could be thousands of lines.
I chose Ganymed-SSH for SSH communication and executed the startShell() method which gave me the login message and last login info but when I try to write to the OutputStream it's not working.

The following line outputs the last login and OS info:

```
 while((line = outputReader.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

But, the following code does not seems to work as expected:

```
OutputStream inputToShell = (shellSession.getStdin());
inputToShell.write(b);
```

Do I need to implement terminal logic? If so, I just need to execute some commands and then show the output to the user, how to proceed?

Comment: Did you send a newline with the command?  The terminal won't process its `stdin` without it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to create a simple Java wrapper around the Ganymed-SSH library that takes the Java's stdin and outputs it to the Shell's stdin, and also pipes the Shell's stdout and stderr to Java's equivalents. In this way you can test how to use the library and what commands to send in which order etc.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final ShellSession shellSession = ...

  Thread input = new Thread() {
    @Override public void run() {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      while(!shellSession.isClosed()) {
        int read = System.in.read(buffer);
        shellSession.getInputStream().write(buffer, read);
      }
    }
  }

  Thread output = ...
  Thread error = ...

  input.start();
  output.start();
  error.start();

}
```